# Why does mongoose try to create a field with "-1" in element for type map?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I got a problem with the new mongoose type Map. 
I use mongoose 5.2.10 and can't update to a newer version at the moment.
I got the problem, that, when using a map in a subdocument, when updating the document I get the error, that mongoDb cannot create a field '-1' in the subdocument, even when not changing the subdocument.

My Schemas

```js
var parentSchema = module.exports = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    child: [childSchema]
}, {
    id: false,
    usePushEach: true
});
parentSchema.updatableAttributes = ["child"];
parentSchema.ignorableAttributes = ["id"];

var textSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foo: { type: String, required: true },
    bar: { type: String, required: true },
    blub: String,
    isSomething: Boolean
}, {
    id: false
});

mapSchema.set("toJSON", {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: util.excludeFields("_id")
});

mapSchema.updatableAttributes = ["foo", "bar", "blub", "isSomething"];
mapSchema.ignorableAttributes = ["id"];


var childSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: String, required: true },
    maps: {type: Map, of: mapSchema}
}, {
    id: false
});


childSchema.updatableAttributes = ["maps"];
childSchema.ignorableAttributes = ["id"];
```

The call

```js
Document.findById(theDocumentId, function (err, document) {
  //add childs without the map schema
  return document.save().then( function(returnDocument) {
    ...
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

always thrown an error:

> Cannot create field '-1' in element {child: ...}

When debugging into the save from mongoose, I saw, that in the `document.$__.activePaths.states.modify`, after the find there are the child routes like `child.-1.maps.$*.foo` or `child.-1.maps.$*.bar` referenced and it seems, that on "save" these are send to mongoDb causing the error. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance